# Ошибка в SQL запросе WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Версия программы: 5.5.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
 insertStr = "INSERT INTO cards (id,cardnumber,seccode,valid_until,c_cards) SELECT ("
                + quotate(dlg_aad.getID()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg_aad.getCardnumber()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg_aad.getAdid()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg_aad.getSeccode())+ ","
                + quotate(dlg_aad.getNcard()) + 
              ") FROM cards WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT id,c_cards FROM cards WHERE id ="+ quotate(dlg_aad.getID()) + " AND c_cards ="+ quotate(dlg_aad.getNcard()) + ")";
```

Делаю запрос через Java, понимаю , что ошибка где-то в мелочах , но не могу понять где конкретно.

Вот код ошибки : `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id,c_cards FROM cards WHERE id ='3' AND c_cards ='2')' at line 1`

Comment: Подзапрос выглядит нормально. Даже выполняется http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9edf53/1
Вы могли бы привести полный текст запроса(то что хранится в `insertStr`) как он у вас сгенерился?

Comment: Например вот так: `INSERT INTO cards (id,cardnumber,seccode,valid_until,c_cards) SELECT (3,1542365821456823,14/2021,548,2) FROM cards WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT id,c_cards FROM cards WHERE id = 3 AND c_cards = 2)`

Comment: http://s02.radikal.ru/i175/1712/f1/40c44e317b96.png

Вот так выглядит таблица, у каждого пользователя может быть несколько карт и мне надо , чтобы при добавлении с админки не было дубликатов. Может быть такая ситуация , что у пользователя с id = 3 админ решит добавить два раза карточку номер 2 ( c_cards = 2) и будет дубликат записи в таблице . Чтобы этого избежать я и хочу сделать этот запрос.

Comment: У вас опечатка в слове `EXISTS`, S - на конце

Comment: Для контроля за уникальностью лучше подходит ключ типа `UNIQUE` по нескольким полям.

Comment: Теперь ошибка : `java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
Вроде бы сравниваю колонки правильно . В чем тут проблема ?

Comment: @Torv я понимаю, но тут не сработает этот ключ , так как они повторяются в таблице , это значение должно быть уникально для одного пользователя.

Comment: Вы зря обернули первый `SELECT` в скобки должно быть [вида](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bbb4)

Comment: У вас id это пользователь? `UNIQUE (id, c_card)` не подойдет?

Comment: @Torv `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'seccode' at row 1`  

вот запрос который получился после ваших советов: `INSERT INTO cards (id,cardnumber,seccode,valid_until,c_cards) SELECT '3','1234567981234567','20/2020','125','2' FROM cards WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id,c_cards FROM cards WHERE id ='3' AND c_cards ='2')`

Comment: Вы перепутали порядок полей, `dlg_aad.getSeccode()` должен быть третьим, а у вас четвертый.

Comment: @Torv, огромное спасибо , что помогаете. Смотрите , у меня `cardnumber` стоит уникальным , но такого значения которое я ввожу ещё не было , но ошибка всё равно летит `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '5555555555555555' for key 'cardnumber' `

Comment: К сожалению, по поводу данной проблемы, могу лишь уточнить: "вы уверены что нет такого значения?" Если можете повторить эту ошибку на менее объемном примере, то это отличный повод задать еще один вопрос =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем запросе три ошибки:

1. Должно быть не `EXIST`, а `EXISTS`
2. После `SELECT` не нужны скобки, запрос должен быть вида:

`INSERT INTO cards (id,c_cards) SELECT 3,1542365821456823`

3. Перечисление полей для записи(в первом `SELECT`) идет не в том порядке, в котором они перечислены для записи, `dlg_aad.getSeccode()` и `dlg_aad.getAdid()` перепутаны местами.

PS: Если вы хотите этим способом обеспечить уникальность, то стоит использовать `UNIQUE(id,c_cards)`.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь!